Pandas resample per ID
I have a DataFrame that looks like this
ID    DateHour               Value
A     2024-05-03 07:00:00    5
A     2024-05-03 09:00:00    2
A     2024-05-03 22:00:00    9
A     2024-05-03 23:00:00    1
B     2024-05-03 02:00:00    8
B     2024-05-03 09:00:00    7
B     2024-05-03 20:00:00    8

I would like to resample it hour wise with the ffill method.
What I'm doing now is selecting one ID, resampling and putting all together.
Is there an easier way to do this?
Here is the expected output
ID    DateHour               Value
A     2024-05-03 07:00:00    5
A     2024-05-03 08:00:00    5
A     2024-05-03 09:00:00    2
A     2024-05-03 10:00:00    2
... 
A     2024-05-03 21:00:00    2
A     2024-05-03 22:00:00    9
A     2024-05-03 23:00:00    1
B     2024-05-03 02:00:00    8
B     2024-05-03 03:00:00    8
... 
B     2024-05-03 08:00:00    8
B     2024-05-03 09:00:00    7
... 
B     2024-05-03 19:00:00    7
B     2024-05-03 20:00:00    8


can you provide an expected output?

assuming your dataframe is df and that the DateHour is already a datetime column, then df.set_index('DateHour').groupby('ID').resample('1H').ffill() should do it

Use groupby with a resample:
result = df.set_index("DateHour").groupby("ID").resample("h").ffill()

